# ToggleClass - how to avoid it conflicting with other libraries?

Tags: javascript, inline, toggleclass

I am using this code for [this website](http://canningsfreerangebutchers.com.au/checkout/) to toggle mobile navigation. But it is causing conflict with the checkout. You can see the 4-step checkout in that page? It becomes one page with no next/place order buttons when the library is on. How do I make this thing work without the library?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "button" ).click(function() {
          $( "div.showMobile" ).toggleClass( "showMobileNav" );
        });    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting how your title is the same as your tags. Please add a more descriptive title.

Comment: What is the code it is interfering with? Seems like nothing major with that small snipplet.

Comment: Please describe the problem clearly; what is happening that shouldn't be happening? What do you expect to see and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mpqvv2mu/

Comment: @epascarello not sure which code its interfering with. right now i removed it. so the mobile navigation is back to not working.

Comment: Edited my main post to explain further the issue. Sorry for confusing you guys.

Answer (score 0):

State $.noConflict(); before your code to avoid conflicts with other libraries using the $ symbol.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  alert("safe to use jQuery's $ here");
  $( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "div.showMobile" ).toggleClass( "showMobileNav" );
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Tried this but issue is still there. I think the library `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` is causing the conflict.